# Jest test formatting -- __tests__ vs *.test.js

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm working in a react codebase where we have test files labeled

```
__tests__
```

The files inside look like this

filename.js

Previously when I've used jest/enzyme, I've had test files formatted like this

filename.test.js

I am assuming that when you put a file inside a folder with the title

```
__tests__
```

you can leave the .test part off? I can't seem to find a solid answer on topic. Does anyone have some insight into the formatting functionality?

Comment: Did you read the docs? This is controlled by [`testMatch`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testmatch-array-string).

Comment: getting rid of `.test.` or `.spec.` part from filename you are making it's harder to open file from IDE: like you typing component name and seeing 2 files with equal filename where you have to put attention to path... not really vital but quite annoying.

Comment: @skyboyer I'm pretty sure most IDEs will allow you to exclude particular files or folders from search. For example in VSCode there is `search.exclude` setting where you can specify something like `**/__tests__`.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is because of the value of jest config's `testMatch` property which defaults to

`[ "**/__tests__/**/*.[jt]s?(x)", "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[jt]s?(x)" ]`

Which basically means that it will consider as a test any js(x) or ts(x) file either with .test (or .spec) after it or inside a `__test__` folder.

Comment: How can I see the jest config's file, I mean what is the location of the jest config file?

Comment: @Arif I couldnt possibly explain it better than this does https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.

Comment: Just in case, more precisely, as of 2023: https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testmatch-arraystring